# VirtualBox virtual machine use on a processor without virtualisation

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to mount a VirtualBox virtual machine on an Intel B980 processor which seems not to have the virtualisation feature.

I have tried to modify the configuration XML into:

```
 <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
        <HardwareVirtEx enabled="false" exclusive="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="false"/>
        <PAE enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
  </CPU>
```

But the log keeps screaming:

```
00:00:00.965297 HWACCM: No VT-x or AMD-V CPU extension found. Reason VERR_VMX_NO_VMX
00:00:00.965320 HWACCM: VMX MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL=0
00:00:00.968180 VM: Halt method global1 (5)
```

Is there a way to bypass this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I have also a processor without virtualization, which normally can be activated in BIOS. My XML, see below, works:

```
  <CPU count="1">
    <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
    <PAE enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
    <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
  </CPU>
```

but don't edit XML file, changes are lost after starting VirtualBox GUI. Do configuration in GUI under VM tab "SYSTEM".